# Can't perform multiple functions on single line?

Tags: php, centos

I just switched servers. On my previous server, and locally on my Mac, I can run this code:

```
$balance = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://paymentwebsite.com?api_crendentials=example'), true)['balance'];
echo $balance;
```

But on my new server, with PHP 5.6 installed, I am forced to do this or PHP breaks completely, leaving no error reports:

```
$balance = file_get_contents('https://paymentwebsite.com?api_crendentials=example');
$balance = json_decode($balance, true);
$balance = $balance['balance'];
echo $balance;
```

What could be causing this and how do I make my new server PHP setup like my old one?

Running CentOS 6.6, if that helps. I've checked over the php.ini but nothing appears to stand out to me. This is the first time I've ever seen something like this.

Comment: Explain "breaks completely".... have you run a `php -l` against the file from the command line? have you checked the webserver error logs?

Comment: Yes. I get a 500 Internal Server error from Apache and nothing from PHP itself.

Comment: Look into the `error.log` then.

Comment: Are you sure you're running PHP 5.6? Can you check the output of `php_info`?